# Sobrepor div sobre outra e posicionar no canto superior direito

Tags: css

Como posso sobrepor uma div com outra e posiciona-la sempre fixa no canto superior direito sempre em relação a div que ela está inserida? tentei com `z-index e position:absolute` mas não obtive exito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa utilizar não apenas position absolute na div que vai sobrepor, mas também position relative na div pai. Segue um exemplo: http://codepen.io/leofontes/pen/VmxZoN

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Qualquer dúvida manda bala que te ajudo ;)